# Weak formulation of a system of biharmonic pdes

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the system of pdes for functions $u,v$
$$\begin{cases} a_0\Delta ^2u+a_1u_{xx}v_{xx}+a_2u_{xy}v_{xy}+a_3u_{yy}v_{yy}  = f\\
b_0\Delta ^2v+b_1u_{xx}v_{xx}+b_2u_{xy}v_{xy}+b_3u_{yy}v_{yy} = g 
\end{cases}$$

subject to homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions over an open bounded connected domain $(x,y) \in \Omega $, where $a_1,a_2,a_3, b_1,b_2,b_3\in L^{2}(\Omega)$, and $a_0>0, b_0>0$ are both constants, $\Delta ^2: =\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)^2=\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}+2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^4}{\partial y^4}$ is the biharmonic operator.

Formulate a weak definition of the solution. What can you say about the existence and uniqueness of $u,v$ based on your weak formulation?

Comment: You will have to assume that $u$ and $v$ are in $H^2(\Omega)$. Consequently, you only need integrate by parts in the bi-harmonic term. Thus, only in the first term a derivative acts on the testfunction. Then check if the induced bilinearform is coercive and continuous (Lax-Milgram).

Comment: Since the equations are coupled, should one multiply a vector to the system with the components of the vector being test functions? If so, then it's equivalent to multiply two different test functions to each of the equations?

Comment: The Hilbertspace $H$ you want to use should be $H=H^2(\Omega)\times H^2(\Omega)= H^2(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$. So to answert your question: yes :)

Comment: I see, but could you demonstrate the first few steps in the form of an answer? I still have difficulty about multiplying the test functions systematicaly in a matrix form and identify the operator $L$.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Followed by 'Quickbeam2k1's comment, following is my weak formulation.

Assume $u,v \in H^2(\Omega)$

Let $(U,V)\in H^2(\Omega)\times H^2(\Omega),$ Multiplying the first and second equation by $U$ and $V$ respectively (how does one write this multiplication abstractly in terms of an operator $L$?) , then employing Greens's identity (integrate by parts) to the biharmonic terms to obtain  $$\begin{cases} a_0\int_{\Omega}\nabla(\Delta u)\cdot \nabla U\mathrm{d}x-a_0\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(\Delta u \frac{\partial U}{\partial n}-U\frac{\partial \Delta U}{\partial n}\right)\mathrm{d}S+\int_{\Omega}C\cdot U\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\Omega}fU\mathrm{d}x\\
b_0\int_{\Omega}\nabla(\Delta v)\cdot \nabla V\mathrm{d}x-b_0\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(\Delta v \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}-V\frac{\partial \Delta V}{\partial n}\right)\mathrm{d}S+\int_{\Omega}D\cdot V\mathrm{d}x  =\int_{\Omega}gV\mathrm{d}x
\end{cases}$$

Where $\begin{cases}C:= a_1u_{xx}v_{xx}+a_2u_{xy}v_{xy}+a_3u_{yy}v_{yy}\\D: = b_1u_{xx}v_{xx}+b_2u_{xy}v_{xy}+b_3u_{yy}v_{yy} \end{cases}$,$$n=\mathrm{the~ outer~ unit~ normal}
$$. 
Is my formulation correct? If so, how to identify the bilinear operator $B$ for Lax-Milgram?

Comment: This looks right. The operator $B$ is now the one induced by your weak formulation, i.e. $B((u,v),(U,V))=$ your weak form ("vector valued")

Comment: Could you explain why we only need to integrate the highest order (biharmonic terms) by parts? Also, since the sum of the lower order terms in the equations are nonlinear, Lax Milgram thus cannot be applied?

Comment: Sorry, I was not reading  carefully enough: 1. Put the divergence on the $\nabla u$ and $\nabla V$. Then all the terms are well-defined in $H^2(\Omega)$. 2. Concerning $C$ and $D$: you are absolutely right. These terms are non-linear. So what to do? The assumption that the coefficients $a_j$ and $b_j$ are in $L^2$ seems to be wrong. $L^\infty$ seems to be more approriate. Howerver, this does not help so far. One could try to iterate. So put $C,D$ on the rhs an indicate $u$ and $v$ there as $u_{\text{old}}$ and $v_{\text{old}}$

Comment: Also think of the boundary data of $U,V$ and $u,v$ in your weak formulation. Maybe it is not necessary to obtain an existence result. Did you check for uniqueness instead?

Comment: I am still thinking about a nonlinear technique to tackle existence, but is it possible to use Lax-Milgram establish the uniqueness in this case?

Comment: I think Lax-Milgram will only help as a starting point in an iteration argument. I think uniqueness, should be obtained, if possible, by the typical procedure: testing with differences (or potentially cacciopolli estimates)